# How to use both string and float DataType in sklearn KNN .fit() method

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

I have a dataset which contains both string and float DataType and I want to train my KNN model with the dataset but it gives a ValueError saying

```
could not covert string to float
```

```
inputs=data.drop(['HeartDisease'],'columns')
output=data.drop(['Age', 'Sex', 'ChestPainType', 'RestingBP', 'Cholesterol', 'FastingBS', 'RestingECG', 'MaxHR', 'ExerciseAngina', 'Oldpeak', 'ST_Slope'],'columns')

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(inputs,output,train_size=0.8)

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
model=KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=31)
model.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

I was expecting the model to be trained with the particular dataset

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In every ML model, you can't use data strings as is. You have to preprocess your input to convert them into numeric type. Except for natural language processing, you probably have a few number of different text values (categorical features).

Example for `'ChestPainType'` column, you should have only 4 values: `['ATA', 'NAP', 'ASY', 'TA']`. Now you have to convert this strings as number: 'ATA': 0, 'NAP': 1, 'ASY': 2, 'TA': 3. In Pandas, you can use [`pd.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) or [`pd.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) to do that but if you use `sklearn`, try [`LabelEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) (especially for `y` target when needed) or [`OneHotEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) (sometimes [`OrdinalEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html)).

The easiest way is to use a [`ColumnTransformer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html).

Reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

# https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/fedesoriano/heart-failure-prediction
data = pd.read_csv('heart.csv')

features = data.drop(columns=['HeartDisease'])
target = df['HeartDisease']

# Text features to convert as numeric. 'M': [1, 0], 'F': [0, 1]
feat_cols = ['Sex', 'ChestPainType', 'RestingECG', 'ExerciseAngina', 'ST_Slope']

ct = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[('le', OrdinalEncoder(), feat_cols)],
    remainder='passthrough'
)

# Convert your data as numeric values
X = ct.fit_transform(features)
y = np.stack(target.values)

# Create 2 datasets for train and test
X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.8)

# Missing step, use `StandardScaler` to normalize numeric values

# Train your model
model = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=31)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Evaluate your model (63% here)
model.score(X_test, y_test)
```

Comment: Is there something that I can do to improve the accuracy. The solution you gave worked but I wanted to know if I could improve the accuracy

Comment: @AkshayBasutkar. The main improvement is to normalize numeric values to avoid to give an important weight to high values.